# Get week number from dates in T-SQL

Tags: date, t-sql

How do I get the week number from dates in T-SQL?

Comment: According to what week numbering schema?

Comment: what week numbering system? ISO?

Comment: and what version of SQL Server are you using? This may make a difference if you want the ISO week number

Answer (score 66):

Have a look at [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())
```

Comment: How about number of weeks between two date @startdate and @enddate

Comment: Try this to find the number of weeks between the variables.
SELECT DATEPART(wk, @enddate) - DATEPART(wk, @startdate)

Comment: Here is a detailed answer and why to use DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GETDATE()) - http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/38682/100185

Answer (score 26):

It is best to use the following:

```
select DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, getDate())
```

As when you have a year with a week 53 as in the case of 2015 it gives unreliable results. (Certainly on 2008 R2)

```
select DATEPART(WK, '01/03/2016')
```

Gives variable results around week 53. When run the week after 3rd Jan it produced the value 1. When run now for the same date it gives the value 2.

Comment: Also, `ISO_WEEK` assumes a week starts on Mondays, and starts counting (1) on the first Monday encountered in the year. `WK` assumes a week starts on Sundays, and starts counting (1) on new years day, regardless of what day it is.

Comment: ...otherwise (as Ewan pointed out) `WK` starts counting from 2 on the first Sunday encountered in the year, if the date is in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Or use DATEDIFF like this: `DATEDIFF(wk,GETDATE(),GETDATE()+7)` to find the number of weeks between two days

Comment: Be careful with DATEDIFF() on the WEEK datepart... it ALWAYS considers Sunday to be the beginning of the week. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql#remarks