# I want to set data from following table group by Weeks in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Date                                Sale               Product Name
+---------------------------+------------+-----------+--------------+ 
2018-10-25 05:27:35.9070422         1000                 P1
2018-10-18 05:27:35.9070422         2000                 P2
2018-10-2 05:27:35.9070422          3050                 P3
2018-10-10 05:27:35.9070422         1000                 P4
2018-10-5 05:27:35.9070422          1000                 P5
```

Let suppose today is 26-05-18

So my result should look like this.

```
 Week                     Sales
+--------------------+------------+
 1                       4050
 2                       1000
 3                       2000
 4                       1000
```

Comment: How do you define "week"?  When does a week begin?

Comment: Can you show your attempt and what error it threw or the incorrect output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the week number you can use PARTDATE() function,
So you query should be :

```
select partdate(WK,r.date) numweek, sum(r.sales) totsales 
from yourtable r
group by partdate(WK,r.date)
```

Take a look please at [Get week number from dates in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317547/get-week-number-from-dates-in-t-sql)

You can also subtruct an N numeric value from partdate(WK,r.date) and then beware of group by clause, to start your selection of weeks with 1.

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

You need `row_number()` :

```
select row_number() over (order by datepart(week, t.date)) as week, sum(t.amount) as sales
from table t
group by datepart(week, t.date);
```

Comment: For what `from table t`? you did not even use that alias.