# Convert date column into week

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datepart

Normally, I write the weeks of the month in my SQL query as follows but I will prepare a dashboard and this dashboard will be based on 2023. For this reason, I cannot write all months this way. How can I write this in SQL in an easy way, and the start date of the week will be Saturday.

Here is my query

```
select 
    dtp.MAIN_CUSTOMER_NUMBER, dtp.TRN_DATE,
    case
        when dtp.TRN_DATE between '20231002' and '20231009' 
            then 'Ekim 1.hafta'
        when dtp.TRN_DATE  between '20231009' and '20231016' 
            then 'Ekim 2.hafta'
        when dtp.TRN_DATE  between '20231016' and '20231023' 
            then 'Ekim 3.hafta'
        when dtp.TRN_DATE  between '20231023' and '20231030' 
            then 'Ekim 4.hafta'
        when dtp.TRN_DATE  between '20231030' and '20231106' 
            then 'Kasım 1.hafta'
        when dtp.TRN_DATE  between '20231106' and '20231112' 
            then 'Kasım 2.hafta'
from 
    BOACARD.TRN.DAILY_TRANSACTION_POOL dtp with (nolock)
```

Comment: Mehmet, what is the database you are using? Would you tag it. Many databases have built-in functions to get the week number, month name etc.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio with SQL Server

Comment: So what is the database, tag it. Oracle? or SQL server? You might be using linked servers and OpenQuery() in which case you might utilize functions from both.

Comment: database is  SQL Server. Can you give some more details?

Comment: According to your current SQL it is a little bit confusing what you are after. How come 1st week in October can be from 2 to 9 inclusive? It is 8 days and also it starts on Monday and includes next Monday. 2nd week starts on 9 and yet another 8 days long week? It is really confusing.

Comment: Agree with @CetinBasoz. If you are date/time values (not date-only values), ranges are best handled as *inclusive* start date/times and *exclusive* end date/times.  Instead of `when dtp.TRN_DATE between '20231002' and '20231009'` you should be writing `when dtp.TRN_DATE >= '20231002' and dtp.TRN_DATE < '20231009'`. (This is likely moot if you start using `DATEPART()`, `DATETRUNC()` or `DATEBUCKET()`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get week number from dates in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317547/get-week-number-from-dates-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first calculate `WeekEndingDate` (Sunday) with a bit of date arithmetic, you can extract the month name using `DATENAME(month, WeekEndingDate)` and the week number (within each month) using the calculation `(DAY(ED.WeekEndingDate) + 6) / 7`.

Resulting logic (including a date-generator).

```
SET LANGUAGE Turkish
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Set Monday (Pazartesi) as first day of week

SELECT
    dtp.TRN_DATE,
    ED.WeekEndingDate,
    CONCAT(
        DATENAME(month, ED.WeekEndingDate),
        ' ',
        (DAY(ED.WeekEndingDate) + 6) / 7,
        '.hafta'
        ) AS Period
FROM (
    SELECT DATEADD(day, S.value, '20231001 12:34') AS TRN_DATE
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 50) S
) dtp
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEADD(
        day,
        7 - DATEPART(weekday, dtp.TRN_DATE),
        CONVERT(DATE, dtp.TRN_DATE)
        ) AS WeekEndingDate
) ED
ORDER BY dtp.TRN_DATE
```

However, the results are slightly different from your original mappings. I am not clear as to why `2023-10-01` is not week 1 (Ekim 1.hafta) and dates `2023-10-08` through `2023-10-08` is not week 2 (Ekim 2.hafta). In contrast, your posted logic places `2023-11-01` is not week 1 (Kasım 1.hafta).

If the selected month and week-number are based on a day other than the last day of the period (perhaps some day mid-week such as Thursday), you may need to calculate slightly different *reference-date* and perform your final calculations based on that.

```
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEADD(
        day,
        4 - DATEPART(weekday, dtp.TRN_DATE),  -- Mid-week Thursday
        CONVERT(DATE, dtp.TRN_DATE)
        ) AS AltReferenceDate
) RD
```

This assigns the week to the month having the most days (4 or more) from that week.

Results (showing both calcuations):

| TRN_DATE | WeekEndDate | Period | AltRefDate | AltPeriod | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 12:34 | 2023-10-01 | Ekim-1.hafta | 2023-09-28 | Eylül 4.hafta |  |
| 2023-10-02 12:34 | 2023-10-08 | Ekim-2.hafta | 2023-10-05 | Ekim 1.hafta | Ekim 1.hafta |
| 2023-10-03 12:34 | 2023-10-08 | Ekim-2.hafta | 2023-10-05 | Ekim 1.hafta | Ekim 1.hafta |
| 2023-10-04 12:34 | 2023-10-08 | Ekim-2.hafta | 2023-10-05 | Ekim 1.hafta | Ekim 1.hafta |
| 2023-10-05 12:34 | 2023-10-08 | Ekim-2.hafta | 2023-10-05 | Ekim 1.hafta | Ekim 1.hafta |
| 2023-10-06 12:34 | 2023-10-08 | Ekim-2.hafta | 2023-10-05 | Ekim 1.hafta | Ekim 1.hafta |
| 2023-10-07 12:34 | 2023-10-08 | Ekim-2.hafta | 2023-10-05 | Ekim 1.hafta | Ekim 1.hafta |
| 2023-10-08 12:34 | 2023-10-08 | Ekim-2.hafta | 2023-10-05 | Ekim 1.hafta | Ekim 1.hafta |
| 2023-10-09 12:34 | 2023-10-15 | Ekim-3.hafta | 2023-10-12 | Ekim 2.hafta | Ekim 2.hafta |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-10-15 12:34 | 2023-10-15 | Ekim-3.hafta | 2023-10-12 | Ekim 2.hafta | Ekim 2.hafta |
| 2023-10-16 12:34 | 2023-10-22 | Ekim-4.hafta | 2023-10-19 | Ekim 3.hafta | Ekim 3.hafta |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-10-22 12:34 | 2023-10-22 | Ekim-4.hafta | 2023-10-19 | Ekim 3.hafta | Ekim 3.hafta |
| 2023-10-23 12:34 | 2023-10-29 | Ekim-5.hafta | 2023-10-26 | Ekim 4.hafta | Ekim 4.hafta |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-10-29 12:34 | 2023-10-29 | Ekim-5.hafta | 2023-10-26 | Ekim 4.hafta | Ekim 4.hafta |
| 2023-10-30 12:34 | 2023-11-05 | Kasım-1.hafta | 2023-11-02 | Kasım 1.hafta | Kasim 1.hafta |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-11-05 12:34 | 2023-11-05 | Kasım-1.hafta | 2023-11-02 | Kasım 1.hafta | Kasim 1.hafta |
| 2023-11-06 12:34 | 2023-11-12 | Kasım-2.hafta | 2023-11-09 | Kasım 2.hafta | Kasim 2.hafta |
| 2023-11-07 12:34 | 2023-11-12 | Kasım-2.hafta | 2023-11-09 | Kasım 2.hafta | Kasim 2.hafta |
| 2023-11-08 12:34 | 2023-11-12 | Kasım-2.hafta | 2023-11-09 | Kasım 2.hafta | Kasim 2.hafta |
| 2023-11-09 12:34 | 2023-11-12 | Kasım-2.hafta | 2023-11-09 | Kasım 2.hafta | Kasim 2.hafta |
| 2023-11-10 12:34 | 2023-11-12 | Kasım-2.hafta | 2023-11-09 | Kasım 2.hafta | Kasim 2.hafta |
| 2023-11-11 12:34 | 2023-11-12 | Kasım-2.hafta | 2023-11-09 | Kasım 2.hafta | Kasim 2.hafta |
| 2023-11-12 12:34 | 2023-11-12 | Kasım-2.hafta | 2023-11-09 | Kasım 2.hafta | ??? |
| 2023-11-13 12:34 | 2023-11-19 | Kasım-3.hafta | 2023-11-16 | Kasım 3.hafta |  |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DZS2iImJ)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use DATEPART() funciton for example

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk,TRN_DATE)
```

Will return an integer for the "week number"

doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Here is how to do it in Oracle

```
SELECT to_number(to_char(to_date(TRN_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW'))
```

doc - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-E118F121-A0E1-4784-A685-D35CE64B4557

---

Note the following is considered Standard SQL and is used in Big Query

```
SELECT extract(week from TRN_DATE)
```

Comment: For `DATEPART(wk,TRN_DATE)` you will need to `SET DATEFIRST 1` to ensure that Monday is set as first day of week. The locale default might be different.

Comment: @TN -- or the local default is what they want :)

Comment: I should have said "might need".

Comment: @TN, this is the biggest pet peeve of mine, people forgetting to handle DATEFIRST. I usually go for: `(DATEPART(dw, somedate) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7` which returns 1 for monday regardless

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your logic exactly but it looks like you are after something like this (not a constant as 'Ekim' and week of year):

```
SET DATEFIRST 6;
SET LANGUAGE turkish;

WITH dates (d)
AS (SELECT DATEADD(d, N - 1, CAST('20230101' AS DATE))
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP (366)
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.object_id) AS N
        FROM master.sys.all_columns t1
            CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns t2
    ) tmp )
SELECT d,
       DATENAME(MONTH, d) + ' '
       + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, d) - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), MONTH(d), 1)) + 1 AS VARCHAR) + '.haftasi'
FROM dates;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/w86vf3CF)